# PATH content is different at two different places

Tags: path, windows-10

Content of path are different:

1.I access path folder by following this path: My computer>properties>Advance system settings>Environment Variable:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.4;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin
```

2.When I type echo %path% on command prompt I am getting this as path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.4;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Python27;setx PATH "C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.4;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Python27;setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Python34\Scripts
```

Note that this path(echo %PATH%) is different that the first one.

My Queries:

1.is it normal having content of path different at these two place ?

2. If its not normal then What could be possible reasons for this (may be something I did)
3. Do I need to sync it? if yes, how ?

**System Details**
OS: Windows 10
Python version 2.7.10

I was having issues with pip command. while investigating that issue I found this one. pip issue is resolved by adding C:\Python27\Scripts to path (first one) as mentioned on some other posts here...

Comment: Are you running a batch file that manipulates the `PATH` variable?

Comment: No I am not running any batch file...

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of environment variables:

1. **System variables** (apply to all users of the computer)
2. **User variables** (specific to each user)

If you navigate to Computer > Properties > Advance system settings > Environment Variables, you will see the User variables at the top of the window and the System variables below. When there is a variable in each section with the same name, they get combined. So, it sounds like you may have a `PATH` variable in each section.

Or, possibly you are running a batch file that manipulates the `PATH` variable.

In your second `PATH` listing, at character 543, it says `setx PATH "C:\Program Files...` and continues on for 1,000+ more characters.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your three questions,

1. Yes, it is normal to have different path entries. One of the paths you give will be your User Path, the other will be the System Path. When you type `echo %PATH%` into the Command Prompt, you look at the environment variable for your User Path.
2. It's quite normal to have different values, you have almost certainly changed your local path to add some extra entries. That's fine as long as you've added what you need to your User Path.
3. You don't need to make sure that the User and System paths are identical. Often they need to be different, for instance when you have installed software that is registered only to one user.

It looks as though your User Path is missing the `C:\Python27\Scripts` entry. Add that to your User path to make sure that you can use pip.

If you're having problems running pip, make sure that your User

try the following command in the Command Prompt:

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python27\Scripts`

Then try to run pip.

Alternatively, change the Path User variable from the Environment Variables window.